In Filamentphp v3 , i am adding custom colors to the panel but they are not showing up
I am trying to add Tailwindcss color preset to my panel in filamentphp v3, but the colors are not being shwon.
I am following the official docs - https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/support/colors#registering-extra-colors
And Below is my PanelProvider code
<?php

namespace App\Providers\Filament;

use App\Filament\Auth\Login;
use Filament\Http\Middleware\Authenticate;
use Filament\Http\Middleware\DisableBladeIconComponents;
use Filament\Http\Middleware\DispatchServingFilamentEvent;
use Filament\Pages;
use Filament\Panel;
use Filament\PanelProvider;
use Filament\Support\Colors\Color;
use Filament\Widgets;
use Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse;
use Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken;
use Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings;
use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession;
use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession;
use Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession;

class PlayerPanelProvider extends PanelProvider
{
    public function panel(Panel $panel): Panel
    {
        return $panel
            ->id('player')
            ->path('player')
            ->login(Login::class)
            ->brandName('KingVouchers')
            ->spa()
            ->colors([
                'danger' => Color::Rose,
                'gray' => Color::Gray,
                'info' => Color::Blue,
                'primary' => Color::Cyan,
                'success' => Color::Emerald,
                'warning' => Color::Orange,
                'indigo' => Color::Indigo,
            ])
            ->discoverResources(in: app_path('Filament/Player/Resources'), for: 'App\\Filament\\Player\\Resources')
            ->discoverPages(in: app_path('Filament/Player/Pages'), for: 'App\\Filament\\Player\\Pages')
            ->pages([
                Pages\Dashboard::class,
            ])
            ->discoverWidgets(in: app_path('Filament/Player/Widgets'), for: 'App\\Filament\\Player\\Widgets')
            ->widgets([
//                Widgets\AccountWidget::class,
//                Widgets\FilamentInfoWidget::class,
            ])
            ->middleware([
                EncryptCookies::class,
                AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
                StartSession::class,
                AuthenticateSession::class,
                ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
                VerifyCsrfToken::class,
                SubstituteBindings::class,
                DisableBladeIconComponents::class,
                DispatchServingFilamentEvent::class,
            ])
            ->authMiddleware([
                Authenticate::class,
            ]);
    }
}


I tried following the docs and i tried running npm run dev and npm run build too, but stil lthe colors wont appear. Besides the 6 default colors provided by Filamentphp i added the Indigo but to no avail.
What should i try now ?

Check Tailwind Configuration
make sure colors are defined in tailwind.config.js

I have no tailwindcss.config.js file . I am just using the Color class to add indigo color to the panel.
By reading the docs i am getting confused. Is it that the Color class can only be used to change the default 6 colors provided by Filamentphp or we can just add any color from Tailwindcss color preset.
Check this  - https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/support/colors#customizing-the-default-colors
